# How to split a compressed zip directory into individual files?

Tags: linux, command-line, zip, compression

If I have a directory with files `A`, `B`, and `C` that is compressed into `dir.zip`, is it possible for me to be able to split up `dir.zip` into `A.zip`, `B.zip`, and `C.zip` without decompressing? From what I understand, during compression, `A`, `B`, and `C` are compressed separately and then concatenated onto each other, but I'm unsure whether there'd be some header/metadata weirdness that might not make it possible to separate the individual compressed components.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can do this:

```
cp dir.zip A.zip
cp dir.zip B.zip
cp dir.zip C.zip
zip -d A.zip B C
zip -d B.zip A C
zip -d C.zip A B
```

Comment: Is there a way to split the files without making copies of `dir.zip`? I'm concerned that if I wanted to do this process on a zip file with a large number of files that it would be space/time inefficient

Comment: It can certainly be done, but I am not aware of a utility that will do it. You would have to write it yourself. There is a utility included with Info-ZIP's zip call zipsplit. zipsplit doesn't do what you want, but you could start with that source code.